# Kotlin basics : RatingBar, listeners

Tags: kotlin, view, listener, ratingbar

I started learning Kotlin few weeks ago and I need help understanding the basics.

1. What is a listener? For example, what is RatingBar's listener? How do I find a listener of other widgets?
2. What are the parameters? Again, what is RatingBar's parameters? How do I find the parameters of other widgets?
3. What is View.____?

Comment: These are actually Android things related to Android's runtime library which can be accessed with Kotlin, Java and some other languages. See https://developer.android.com/. For e. g. the RatingBar look at https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/RatingBar (but you should look at some tutorials and basic examples first).

Answer (score 0):

If you're writing a component that handles events of some kind, you'll probably want a way to inform other components about those events. There are lots of ways to do this (in a software design sense), and one of those is the idea of a *listener*.

The basic idea is that components can register themselves as listeners, and when a relevant thing happens, they get a callback. The component generating the events doesn't need to know what those listeners are, it just needs to hold a reference to one (or more) and call some callback function when the event happens. The key thing here is that the component doesn't *have* a listener, you have to provide them. You're hooking components up.

---

So a typical way to do this is for a component to implement a callback interface, which basically says "I have a function called this with these parameters" and the event component can just call that function with the details when an event happens. You could also create an object  that implements that interface, or in Kotlin's case you can just pass a function in that matches the signature of the callback function - basically providing a block of code that says "when the event happens, do this stuff in response". That's typically how you define behaviour, like setting an on-click listener - you write a block of code to execute when the user clicks a thing, and when the event happens, that code gets run.

---

I hope that makes sense generally - if any of it's confusing (since you're new) I'd recommend reading the basic trails in the [Java Tutorials](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/index.html) (which Kotlin is based on) to get a handle on interfaces and the like.

As for the other questions... if you're asking what the parameters are when you construct a `RatingBar` or whatever, the best place to look is the [documentation](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/RatingBar) (although you generally won't be constructing `View`s in code anyway, just adding them to a layout XML file) - Android Studio should pop up some hints too (you can hit ctrl+q for documentation on the thing your cursor is currently over, or ctrl+p for parameter hints).

If you're asking what a `View` is, it's the base class for Android's UI components, it's really anything that's able to draw itself and be included in a layout. It has a *lot* of methods because it has a lot of functionality built in to handle all these UI responsibilities.

If you're asking what `View.something` is, that's a static method or field defined on the `View` class - if you don't know what that means, read the Java tutorial link I included! You'll typically be referencing things like `View.VISIBLE` which is a set value you provide to a `View's` `setVisibility` method - it knows what those values mean and what to do with them